# WiFi Connection on Boot: Setting up WiFi from micro SD card in Raspberry Pi

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, headless, netplan, ubuntu-mate

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with OS Ubuntu Mate 20.04. My goal is for the pi to connect immediately to wifi upon boot, so that I can connect to it with ssh. To do this, I want to be able to set up the WiFi complete with WiFi SSID, Pword, and static IP address by reading and writing to the micro SD card from my laptop.

I've tried this so far by configuring /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml as shown[image].

But nothing happens when I turn the pi on. It does not automatically connect. Am I supposed to activate it somehow? Originally, the yaml file did not have anything from "wifis:". Do I need to create a separate yaml file?

I've found other sites that talk about this, but cannot find any that discuss the FIRST time setup being headless with the micro SD card from a laptop. I want to be able to do this, so that wherever I go to new WiFi networks, I can search for the required information from my laptop, configure it on the micro SD card, turn the Pi on, and then do all of my work on the Pi via ssh, such that literally the only components required are the pi, micro SD card reader, and my laptop.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please see `https://netplan.io` and `https://netplan.io/examples`.